# On moment generating function differentiability.

Tags: measure-theory, moment-generating-functions

I am studying Moment generating functions from a Measure Theory perspective and I've found some difficulties with this exercise.

> Let $X$ be a positive random variable on the probability space
>   $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$.  The function $\phi(t):=\int_{\Omega} e^{-tX}
>  dP$ is the moment generating function. Now I am asked to show that the
>   latter is $m$-times differentiable at $t=0+$ if the absolute moment
>   $\int |X|^m dP<\infty$.

In my textbook the author simply states that :

$$|\frac {d^{m}}{dt^m} \phi(t)|=|X^m e^{-tX}|\leq X^m \color{red}*$$

And then, applying $m$-times Dominated Convergence he obtains that 
$$ \phi^{(m)}_X(0+)=(-1)^m\int X^mdP$$

$\color{red}*$ This would only hold true if $t\geq 0$ but, in general one assumes that $t\in\mathbb R$.

Is there some additional assumption I'm missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You  can have $E|X|<\infty$ but $Ee^{tX}=\infty$ for all $t>0$. So the MMG need not be finite when $t<0$.

Comment: So can I assume that $t$ is positive for the sake of the exercise?

Comment: Yes, it is not poassible use negative values of $t$ in general.